# Install bootstrap CMS on hostgator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, content-management-system

I'm trying to figure out how to install bootstrap cms on hostgator.  I changed the PHP configuration to PHP 5.5 and uploaded the extracted files to my root domain.  From there, I have no idea what to do...I'm new to programming and really only good at html/css/jquery so far.

The directions on https://github.com/BootstrapCMS/CMS seem like it's for a setting up on your computer...How do I set this up on Hostgator?

Thanks!